# Update not validating on Mongoose connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i add using the below mongoose schema the validation will work, but when i update even if i leave some required field empty the validation will still pass. what am i missing

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const slug = require("mongoose-slug-generator")
mongoose.plugin(slug)

const imagePath = 'uploads/blogImages'


const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Blog Title is required"],
    trim: true,
  },

  image: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Blog Image is required"],
  },

  desc: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Blog Body is required"],
  },

  slug: {
    type: String,
    slug: "title"
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

blogSchema.virtual('imagePath').get(function() {
  if (this.image != null) {
    return path.join("/", imagePath, this.image);
  }
})


const blogModel = mongoose.model('blogs', blogSchema)
module.exports = blogModel
module.exports.imagePath = imagePath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which update function you're using, [the validators may not run by default](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#validating).

If you're currently using `model.updateOne()`, I suggest trying to use `model.findOneAndUpdate()` instead, as it has validators by default.

Alternatively, you can pass options to explicitly run the validators on `updateOne()`, like so: `model.updateOne(query, update, { runValidators: true })`

Comment: am using model.findByIdAndUpdate()

Comment: Hmm interesting. Which version of Mongoose are you using? Also could you share the code that is actually running the update?

Comment: I just add {runValidators: true} as the third parameter to findOneAndUpdate() and validation is now working for update. Thank you so much